# Where are variables and watches in the Xcode debuggger?

Tags: xcode, debugging

I am in the `Xcode` debugger.  I do see the console `print` outputs and the `llvm` at the bottom . But the debugger buttons and most notably the variables/watches are not showing. I have looked through all the menu options and clicked on many tiny icons trying to discover how to have them show.

[image]

What is the IDE command to show the debugger variables and watches?

Comment: Your screen shot crops out the button you need to click. It’s at the bottom right but I can’t point to it, you have hidden it.

Comment: @matt Thanks!  `Show variables view` . I hate GUI's and clicking on every icon on the screen hoping it might be the right one . Put it in the menu!  Btw i had to crop because of sensitive info printed - which should not be. I need the debugger to solve ;)

Comment: Well, presumably you are the one who started this by clicking it the first time and causing the variables pane to be hidden. :)

Comment: Maybe so - but I was diverted from Xcode for several weeks and have to re-acquaint.  Why would options not be available in the Menu and only via icons ..

Comment: Because, uh, Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the middle of these three icons:

[image]

Comment: awarding in 4 mins tic toc